# How to make one event to identify whether multiple radio buttons are checked?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, radio-button, groupbox

I have the following code which checks each radio button (Temp30, Temp40 and Temp60) and does the necessary things such as turning the wash temperature light on etc...

I want to create an event which handles all 3 radio buttons. I thought it could possibly have something to do with the groupbox they are in? (it is called TempGroupBox)

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
private void Temp30_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Temp30.Checked)
    {
        MainDisplayLabel.Text = ("   SELECT SPIN SPEED");
        WashTempLight.Visible = true;
        WashTempLight.Image = Properties.Resources._30degrees;
        SpeedGroupBox.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void Temp40_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Temp40.Checked)
    {
        MainDisplayLabel.Text = ("   SELECT SPIN SPEED");
        WashTempLight.Visible = true;
        WashTempLight.Image = Properties.Resources._40degrees;
        SpeedGroupBox.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void Temp60_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Temp60.Checked)
    {
        MainDisplayLabel.Text = ("   SELECT SPIN SPEED");
        WashTempLight.Visible = true;
        WashTempLight.Image = Properties.Resources._60degrees;
        SpeedGroupBox.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind all radioButton's event to the same handler and  use `sender` parameter to  get the control  that the action is for.

```
private void Temps_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkedName = ((RadioButton)sender).Name;

    if(checkedName == "Temp40")
    {
        ...
    }
    else if(checkedName == "Temp60")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can add event handler for all RadioBUttons's like that after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
var radioButtons =this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();

foreach (RadioButton item in radioButtons)
{
      item.CheckedChanged += Temps_CheckedChanged;
}
```

Comment: @MartinJames ) Thanks, but I must add spaces before and after `=` to make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @FarhadJabiyev however this doesn't seem to work.. do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @user3625434 Why it does not work? Is there any exception? It must work. Have you tried to put breakpoint and debug the code?

Comment: @user3625434 Have you changed radioButtons `Changed` event to `Temps_CheckedChanged`?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev sorry I am new to this! Do I need to create a new event at the top of the code or something? For c# to recognise it?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev no I haven't... how do I do this?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev                                               Temp30.Checked += new Temps_CheckedChanged;
Temp40.Checked += new Temps_CheckedChanged;
Temp60.Checked += new Temps_CheckedChanged;                                Is this what I need to do?

Comment: @user3625434 See my update. You must change Checked to `CheckedChanged`.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev im sorry but it says "Cannot assign method group to an implicity-typed local variable" and 'radioButtons' is underlined in blue ?

Comment: @user3625434 Are you using WinForms? or WPF?

Comment: Got it to work doing this: Temp30.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Temps_CheckedChanged);
            Temp40.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Temps_CheckedChanged);
            Temp60.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Temps_CheckedChanged); Thank you for your help! @FarhadJabiyev

Comment: @user3625434 The reason of my update does not work, may be that your RadioButtons in some container. If this is the case, the you can change `this.Controls` to something like that: `this.YourRadioButtonsContainer.Controls`.